# Resampling pandas frame with function depending on column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a recurring issue where I have data frames in which some columns are angles while others are not, and I'd like to resample in such a way that mean values are computed correctly for each type.  Here is a small example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def angleMean(x):
    d2r = np.pi/180.
    cosMean = np.mean(np.cos(x * d2r))
    sinMean = np.mean(np.sin(x * d2r))
    return np.arctan2(sinMean,cosMean) / d2r

# Define data fame
t = pd.date_range("00:00", "3:00", freq="30min")
df = pd.DataFrame({'t':t,'x':[350.,0.,2.,4.,6.,8.,10.],'theta':[350.,0.,2.,4.,6.,8.,10.]}).set_index('t')

# Using normal mean
print df.resample('1H').mean()

# Using angular mean
print df.resample('1H').apply(angleMean)
```

The above examples shows either type of averaging applied to all columns to get the resampling.

Is there a good way that I can define a function that uses the column name to determine the correct averaging to apply to each column?

Comment: So in other words you would like to 'specialize', something like `angleMean(x, column)`, where code inside runs differently depending on the `column` it is applied to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `apply`, you pass each column of the DataFrame to the specified function as a Series-Object. You can get the name of the Series (i.e. the column name) via the `.name` attribute:

```
def conditionalMean(x):
  if x.name == 'theta':
    return angleMean(x)
  else:
    return x.mean()

print df.resample('1H').apply(conditionalMean)
```